# PYTHON CHALLENGE: Creating a program that processes .txt file and counts # of occurrences of each character

Tags: python

I've already programmed code that accomplishes this task by doing something along the lines of

```
import collections
def main():
    c = collections.Counter()
    inFile = open("Text.txt", 'r')
    for line in inFile:
        c += collections.Counter(line)
    for key in c:
        print(key, "character occurs", c[key], "times.")
    inFile.close()
main()
```

This code accomplishes the task, BUT, it contains 10 lines of executable code - I need to find a way to do this in 4 lines of code or less... Lines of code include module imports, function definitions, and function calls. It is NOT okay to compress programming structures to make code fit on fewer lines:

Ex:

```
for i in range(20): code...
def main(): code ....
```

I can't for the life of me figure this out. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If your code is working then ask on [codereview](http://http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why four lines of code or less? I'm just curious.

Comment: Code works, but does not meet guidelines.

Comment: @ProfOak - This is for a challenge

Comment: How about `print("\n".join("{} occurs {} times".format(k,v) for k,v in __import__("collections").Counter(open("text.txt").read()).items()))`

Comment: No, I want tips on how to tackle this. Not looking for sass

Comment: Are you trying to find rare occurrences in challenge number 2?

Comment: Voting to close because it's hard to determine a good answer and nebulous list of hints is unlikely to help future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe move this to PPCG: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, starting with your code:

```
import collections
def main():
    c = collections.Counter()
    inFile = open("Text.txt", 'r')
    for line in inFile:
        c += collections.Counter(line)
    for key in c:
        print(key, "character occurs", c[key], "times.")
    inFile.close()
main()
```

We can remove the main function and call:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
inFile = open("Text.txt", 'r')
for line in inFile:
    c += collections.Counter(line)
for key in c:
    print(key, "character occurs", c[key], "times.")
inFile.close()
```

This nets us 2 lines -- down to 8.  We can also use a `with` context manager to save a line on the file closing:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
with open("Text.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        c += collections.Counter(line)
    for key in c:
        print(key, "character occurs", c[key], "times.")
```

Down to 7.  We can also create a single `Counter` object, initialized over the entire file contents, instead of creating one and updating it with values from each line:

```
import collections
with open("Text.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    c = collections.Counter(inFile.read())
    for key in c: 
        print(key, "character occurs", c[key], "times.")
```

Down to 5.  We can also cheat and put that last for loop and body on the same line:

```
import collections
with open("Text.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    c = collections.Counter(inFile.read())
    for key in c: print(key, "character occurs", c[key], "times.")
```

Which gives us 4 lines, but it may violate the "It is NOT okay to compress programming structures to make code fit on fewer lines" rule.  We can be less cheaty by doing something like:

```
import collections
with open("Text.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    c = collections.Counter(inFile.read())
    print('\n'.join("{!r} character occurs {} times".format(k,v) for k,v in c.items()))
```

It's not the prettiest, but it's 4 lines.

---

Of course you could go further, skipping the creation of the intermediary `c` object:

```
import collections
with open("Text.txt", 'r') as inFile:
    print('\n'.join("{!r} character occurs {} times".format(k,v) for k,v in collections.Counter(inFile.read()).items()))
```

And if you didn't care about closing the file:

```
import collections
print('\n'.join("{!r} character occurs {} times".format(k,v) for k,v in collections.Counter(open("Text.txt", 'r').read()).items()))
```

To go to 1 line with an import you could use the creative (and crazy) solution suggested by Kevin in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
# try to figure out how to count occurances in a string
rare = [letter for letter in letters if count_is_one]
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach was right for using a dictionary kind of data type.

Key things:

1. Using `with open() as f` because it automatically closes the file
   when the block ends. So you don't need to use a line to close the
   file.
2. Avoid using imports when you can, because they waste lines.
3. If you make a main function, you're wasting 1 line calling it, and 1 line defining it.

Code:

```
with open("example_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    counts = dict( (c, contents.count(c)) for c in set(contents) )
for key in counts: print "%s occurred %d times" % (key, counts[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in one line. This uses sets and dict comprehensions to do it. It also filters out the newlines by using setwise difference. I'm assuming you didn't want to count newlines.

```
print {i:open("foo.txt").read().count(i) for i in set(open("foo.txt").read())-{"\n"}}
```

It prints out a nice dictionary:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'g': 5, 'f': 2, 'i': 2, 'h': 2, 'k': 1, '.': 4, 'p': 4, 's': 3, 'r': 1, ':': 4, 'y': 2, 'n': 6, 'z': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints out each character found in the file `input.txt` and its number of appearances.

`input.txt`:

```
hsvkjlheswufWEJHBKJDHEEIUIneeiww..ziep
```

Line of code:

```
temp = [print(letter, (len(open('input.txt', 'r').read())-len(open('input.txt', 'r').read().replace(letter, '')))) for letter in sorted(set(open('input.txt', 'r').read()))]
```

Result:

```
. 2
B 1
D 1
E 3
H 2
I 2
J 2
K 1
U 1
W 1
e 4
f 1
h 2
i 2
j 1
k 1
l 1
n 1
p 1
s 2
u 1
v 1
w 3
z 1
```